# First line of Python script's subprocess output not immediately available

Tags: python

I want to execute python scripts form another python script. I am using:

### hello.py

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from time import sleep
print 'hello'
sleep(10)
print 'world!'
```

### host.py

```
#! usr/bin/env python
import shlex
from subprocess import PIPE, STDOUT, Popen

cmd = 'python hello.py'
p = Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
    print line.rstrip()
```

However, instead of printing `hello` immediately and `world` after a 10-second delay, `hello` is delayed for 10 seconds.

What is the cause of this delay? How can it be avoided?

Comment: This isn't specific to calling Python from Python -- you'd have the same behavior with the called process in any language that uses the same output buffering policy as the standard C library.

Comment: You don't need shlex for that command a simple split will work or just pass the commands in a list

Comment: I am running such script on Windows and Linux. For some reasons, it didn't work on Linux after removing shlex!

Answer (score 1):

Line buffering is often implicit only when stdout is direct to a terminal -- meaning **not** when it's run to a pipeline.

Compare the behavior you're already seeing to that of:

```
print 'hello'
sys.stdout.flush() ## force the buffer the flush here
sleep(10)
print 'world!'
```

Comment: alternatively, IIRC, you could run the command `python -u hello.py` which sets python to be in unbuffered mode by default.

Comment: What if I have a big script? Do I have to flush after each output?

Comment: @mgilson I have tried your method and (so far) it is working.

Comment: @Omar, *why* you want to flush after each line matters. If it's a big enough script, generating enough output, flushes will happen automatically with a reasonable level of frequency; unless you're doing something latency-sensitive, the default behavior is optimized for improving throughput, and can actually be more efficient than the default flush-on-every-line. Which is to say: The default is default for a reason; only change it if you need to. But if you _do_ need to, `python -u` is a fine approach.

Comment: Well, I am writing a scripts requires a user interaction. Without being able to see whats going on, scripts will exit with timeout error.

Comment: If this is interacting with a user, why not connect it directly to the TTY, rather than having the intermediate program pass things back and forth? Connecting to a TTY also has the benefit of making everything line-buffered by default. :)